# Add a new field to a PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

What I have is this:

```
SELECT Value AS FieldName, [42] AS [KeyID_42],[600] AS [KeyID_600]
INTO ##Temp311037
FROM
(
  SELECT TransID, Value, FieldName
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT TransID, Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountNbr]) AS [AccountNbr], [CoAdd1]) AS [CoAdd1], Convert(VarChar(250), [CoAdd2]) AS [CoAdd2], Convert(VarChar(250), [CoCity]) AS [CoCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [CoFax]) AS [CoFax]
     FROM tblSQLContacts
  ) p
  UNPIVOT
  (
    FieldName FOR Value IN 
    ([accountNbr], [CoAdd1], [CoAdd2], [CoCity], [CoFax])
   )AS unpvt
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  MAX(FieldName)
  FOR TransID IN ([42],[600])
) AS PivotTable
WHERE [42] <> [600]
```

And my output looks like this:

```
FieldName           KeyID_42        KeyID_600
AccountNbr          55664           55635
ChoiceFundYN        0               1
CoAdd1              PO Box 2200     1500 Mountain Drive
CoAdd2              PO Box 7004     PO Box 4300
CoCity              Las Vegas       Birmingham
CoFax               5552355622      5552975152
```

And this data comes from the table `tblSQLContacts`.  Well, the problem is that I'm going to have a massive `UNION` of about 20 tables.  So, I'd like to be able to add the table name to this output, in its own field.  So the end result would be:

```
FieldName           KeyID_42        KeyID_600           Table
AccountNbr          55664           55635               tblSQLContacts
ChoiceFundYN        0               1                   tblSQLContacts
CoAdd1              PO Box 2200     1500 Mountain Drive tblSQLContacts
CoAdd2              PO Box 7004     PO Box 4300         tblSQLContacts
CoCity              Las Vegas       Birmingham          tblSQLContacts
CoFax               5552355622      5552975152          tblSQLContacts
```

Is this possible?  I can't seem to make it work.  Ideally I'd like it to be the first field, but I'll take it anywhere I can get it.

Comment: You could put a hard coded column inside your pivot subquery called table with the value of your table name - since the value is the same for each row, it shouldn't impact your pivot.

Comment: I changed the first line to SELECT 'tblSQLContacts' AS TableName, Value AS FieldName, [42] AS [KeyID_42],[600] AS [KeyID_600] and that worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to add the table name to the query, you are going to need to add a hard-coded value to your pivot query or subquery.  You can make a change to your query to be something like this:

```
SELECT Value AS FieldName, 
   [42] AS [KeyID_42],[600] AS [KeyID_600],
   TableName
INTO ##Temp311037
FROM
(
  -- add hard-coded value here
  SELECT TransID, Value, FieldName, 'tblSQLContacts' as TableName
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT TransID, Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountNbr]) AS [AccountNbr], 
        [CoAdd1]) AS [CoAdd1], 
        Convert(VarChar(250), [CoAdd2]) AS [CoAdd2], 
        Convert(VarChar(250), [CoCity]) AS [CoCity], 
        Convert(VarChar(250), [CoFax]) AS [CoFax]
      FROM tblSQLContacts
   ) p
  UNPIVOT
  (
     FieldName 
     FOR Value IN ([accountNbr], [CoAdd1], [CoAdd2], [CoCity], [CoFax])
  )AS unpvt
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  MAX(FieldName)
  FOR TransID IN ([42],[600])
) AS PivotTable
WHERE [42] <> [600]
```

Since the value will be the same for each row, it should not alter your result of the pivot.